# How can I add a footer to every page that links to the table of contents page?

Tags: table-of-contents, footer

The table of contents position could change during the writing of the PDF and I don't really know what to do. I'm a still a beginner using LaTeX.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to add the table of contents to the booksmark?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer makes sense... How can I do that though?

Comment: Besides hyperref, you will need to change the footers for both plain and headings (or fancy) page styles.  If the TOC already has a target (see aux file), just use `\hyperlink{target}{\thepage}`.